# Start > Run autocomplete list is populated with non-MRU and non-existent files

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, autocomplete

If I go to Start > Run and type `d:`, the autocomplete list is populated with lots of files which have long since been deleted from d: and that I have never run via Start > Run (should not be in MRU). How can I refresh this list?

I'm guessing it's using the Indexing Service or something, but can anyone point to official documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for after I looked at @surfasb's suggestion.

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs

I can selectively delete the files that are missing from there, or I can delete them all or via the file ext subkeys.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to do this.

Carpet bomb method.

Right click taskbar, then Properties.  Clear the Recently Run programs box and hit OK.

Registry key method.

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU

The official docs....

Hummm. . . . . .  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Clear-the-Run-history-on-the-Start-menu

They even give you pretty colors.

Comment: Or a third method: CCleaner: http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER Though it cleans other stuff, too.

Comment: Yeah, there are literally 1000 ways to skin this cat. . .